# Show View in Telerik Report Designer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, telerik-reporting, report-designer

Along with a stored procedure I also want view to be displayed when we select stored procedure radio button in SQL Data Source Component Telerik Report Designer.

How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get a list of your views in the data source component configuration screen is this:

1. Click on the "Select Statement" radio button instead of the "Stored Procedure" one
2. Click on the Query Builder button
3. When the "Add Table" screen pops up click on the "Views" tab

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I am sorry but there is No (not able to Find) "Query Builder Button" in data source component configuration screen.
I am using Web Report Designer.
https://demos.telerik.com/reporting/designer
Please let me know if there is any other way to do the same. Thank you

Comment: I thought you were asking about the Report Designer extension for Visual Studio. Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can get a list of views in the web designer. If it is important to have such a list then maybe you can work around this issue by creating stored procedure wrappers for each of your view?
Or paste this "SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(v.object_id) schema_name, v.name FROM sys.views as v" in the "Select Statement" box, click "Execute Query" on the next screen and go back :)))